# Algorithm itemset matching pattern

Tags: algorithm

I've a set of elements (potentially big) with an order relation:

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

and a set of frequent patterns (potentially big) with ids:

```
[a]:1,[b]:2,[c]:3,[a,b]:4,[b,c]:5,[a,b,c]:6
```

I have a sequence of ordered sets:

```
[a,b], [e], [c], [e,f], [a,b,c]
```

I want to match every set in the sequence with the ids of the corresponding patterns:

```
[a,b]:{1,2,4}, [e]:{}, [c]:{3}, [a,b,c]:{1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

My goal is to limit the number of passes over the sequence so I want to build a data structure I can use during the scan.
I'm thinking of a prefix tree:

```
──null
   ├──a : 1
   |  |
   |  └──b : 4
   |     |
   |     └──c : { 5, 6 }
   |
   ├──b : 2
   |  |
   |  └──c : 5
   |
   └──c : 3
```

I scan a set in the sequence and pass it trough the tree multiple times **recursively** (set, set.tail, set.tail.tail...), every time I reach a node I add the corresponding ids to an array.

Do I miss any peculiar case in my reasoning (just realized I have to put multiple ids for nodes of `depth>2` if I don't want to miss [a,c] if [a,b,c] exist in the set) ?
Is there any more sophisticated data structure I can use to improve the processing time ?

Edit : In fact at depth n, I need `2^(n-2)` ids with my method (considering my tree is dense). I'm not sure it's a valid way to do it...

Edit2 : another approach merging bitmaps of each single element in the sequence to build each pattern (as used in **SPADE** algorithm).

```
a  : [1,0,0,0,1]
b  : [0,1,0,0,1]
ab : [0,0,0,0,1]
```

with some array manipulations, I should be able to match this with the elements of my initial array.

Comment: You can build a DFA ("dictionary engine") to recognise *all* six patterns in a stream. (this is essentially what fgrep does)

Comment: @wildplasser, I have potentially a lot of elements and patterns (the only constraints is elements are sorted in a pattern), Is dfa still a valid approach  ? Do you have any reference for implmentation ?

Comment: http://www.dcs.kcl.ac.uk/staff/mac/TSP/http://www.dcs.kcl.ac.uk/staff/mac/TSP/ (first chapter,pg 47, IIRC) Or possibly the dragon book.

Comment: @wildplasser, I had a look at the dictionary matching lecture and ended on this wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm but looks like it only considers exact matching so in my case it won't detect [a,c] in [a,b,c].

Comment: What is your *actual* problem?  It seems like you've got a problem which you could solve if you could solve this one efficiently.  But you're going to be putting an exponential number of ids in for every long set in your sequence, so there is no efficient solution.

However your original problem may be easier.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realise that it is allowed to skip/ignore tokens, without *resetting* the state. For a single n-token searchpattern your problem would reduce to n+1 states. Combining more (than one) pattern states would blow up the number of states. (but in practice, fewer than the Carthesian product would be needed, IMHO)

Comment: Looks like the best way to do it is by merging bitmaps of the position of each single element in the sequence to build the different patterns.

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't understand this "I want to match every set in the sequence with the ids of the corresponding patterns."

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a prefix tree (aka trie), all nodes are unique, so the prefix tree for the set `{a,b,c}` *in alphabetic order with continuity* look like this:

```
──null
   ├──a : 1
   |  |
   |  └──b : 4
   |     |
   |     └──c : 6
   |
   ├──b : 2
   |  |
   |  └──c : 5
   |
   └──c : 3
```

And it maps to the prefix set `{ a, b, c, ab, bc, abc }`.

The tree space complexity is `SUM k for k = 1..N ~ O(N^2)`.

**Node.java**

```
class Node
{
    public String str;
    public ArrayList<String> child;

    public Node (String str)
    {
        this.str = str;
        this.child = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```

**MyTree.java**

```
class MyTree
{
    Node head;

    ..

    public void build_tree(String [] symbol)
    {
        this.head = new Node("");
        build(symbol,head,0,symbol.length-1);
    }

    // build the prefix tree through DFS
    private void build(String [] symbol, Node parent, int start, int end)
    {
        Node ch = null;
        for (int i=start; i<=end; i++)
        {
            ch = new Node(symbol[i]);
            parent.child.add(ch);

            if (end - start > 0)
            {
                build(symbol,ch,i,end);
            }
        }
    }
}
```